# How with one function and one form to enter multiple rows in DB with same inputs - Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Here is explanation of my question.

I have usual form and it is not clear to me how with one function and one form to enter multiple rows in the same database table with same form inputs because in my case I have the ingredients of products and every ingredients should be new row in database. The only solution I know is to make add one ingredient at a time but it is not a good solution... I might know how to solve it with classical php functions but I do not know with laravel functions, is probably easier with laravel.

This is function:

```
  public function post_add()
{

    if(Input::get('submit'))
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $validation = Validator::make($input);

        if($validation->fails())
        {
            Vsession::cadd('r',  $validation->errors->first())->cflash('status');
        }
        else
        {
            $items['product_weight']          = Input::get('product_weight');
            $items['product_code']          = Input::get('product_code');
            $items['raw_material']          = Input::get('raw_material');


            foreach ($items as $key => $value)
            {
                $items[$key] = ($value !== '') ? trim(filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : null;
            }
            try
            {

                $id = DB::table('products_ingredients')->insert_get_id(array(
                                        'product_weight'          => $items['product_weight'],
                                        'product_code'          => $items['product_code'],
                                        'raw_material'          => $items['raw_material'],
                ));
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                Vsession::cadd('r',  __('error'))->cflash('status');
                return Redirect::to_action('products@add');
            }

            Vsession::cadd('g', __('error'))->cflash('status');
            return Redirect::to_action('products@add');
        }
    }

    return $this->get_add();
}
```

and add.php

```
    <?php
echo Form::text('product_weight', Input::get('product_weight'));
echo Form::text('product_code', Input::get('product_code'));
echo Form::text('raw_material', Input::get('raw_material'));
?>
```

But I need to repeat inputs several times, like this:

```
    <?php
echo Form::text('product_weight', Input::get('product_weight'));
echo Form::text('product_code', Input::get('product_code'));
echo Form::text('raw_material', Input::get('raw_material'));

echo Form::text('product_weight', Input::get('product_weight'));
echo Form::text('product_code', Input::get('product_code'));
echo Form::text('raw_material', Input::get('raw_material'));

....
?>
```

I hope I managed to explain.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could make another table called ingrediens:

ID | value | prod_id

And there you could store all ingredients for each product. Then when inserting datas you could just use foreach and insert them in loop

Hope it is useful

Answer (score 0):

to repeat this code

```
<?php
    echo Form::text('product_weight[]', Input::get('product_weight'));
    echo Form::text('product_code[]', Input::get('product_code'));
    echo Form::text('raw_material[]', Input::get('raw_material'));
?>
```

preform it in a loop and it should works with you

---

im not good with laravel but here is an example for loops

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    The current value is {{ $i }}
@endfor

@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach

@while (true)
    <p>I'm looping forever.</p>
@endwhile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution to this is a little manual...

Take the most basic example...

```
<div class="name">
    {{ Form::text('name[]') }}
</div>
```

If you use some javascript, you can duplicate this entire DIV as many times as you want (using something like $('name').clone())

You could retrieve this in your PHP with...

```
$names = Input::get('name');
foreach($names as $name){
    //do whatever you want
}
```

**The original question was how do you do this with MORE than one field (ie. name and age). The only answer I can think of is something like this**

```
<div class="person">
    {{ Form::text('persons[ID][name]') }}
    {{ Form::text('persons[ID][age]') }}
</div>
```

But you would have to set the ID every time you copied the rows... there has to be a better way?